# How do I write a test for a function that should do nothing?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

Sometimes, I write functions that, under certain circumstances, should do nothing. Not only is it acceptable that they don't do anything, but it is actually the required behavior. Is there a pattern to test a function to make sure it has no side effects?

---

As an example, I'm currently testing a function that looks like this:

```
function onRowOfIconsClicked(iconName) {
  if (iconName === 'new') {
    doSomeAwesomeStuffImAlreadyTesting();
  }
  // We haven't implemented the other icons yet, so for now,
  // do nothing and don't throw an error if a different icon
  // is clicked
}
```

How would I write a test case to assert the current requirement that when `onRowOfIconsClicked` is called with an `iconName` other than `"new"`, the function does nothing?

Comment: I could write a test that ensures the specific side effects the function typically causes don't occur. And if that's the only pattern for a test like this, that's what I'll do. I'm wondering if there's a more elegant or commonly used pattern that I'm unaware of, though.

Comment: How complicated are these functions? Could you create a spy for both `onRowOfIconsClicked()` and `doSomeAwesomeStuffImAlreadyTesting()` and if `iconName != 'new'` then the first spy should be invoked once and the second not at all. Assuming the code above is how it is actually structured.

Comment: I guess you could have the function set `arguments.callee.did_nothing = 1` in an `else` block in the event that it does nothing else...

Comment: Ask yourself why you need to test that particular case. Is there maybe a better way to structure the code that doesn't require a no-op? Do you want to make it harder for yourself in the future if you want to do something later?

Answer (score -1):

All JavaScript functions have a return value, even if that return value is `undefined` because of no explicit `return` statement used to specify a return value.

What you can do then, is test that if the function is called with an `iconName` parameter other than `'new'`, then test that the function returns `undefined`. Because `undefined === undefined` and so will pass the test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to ensure that the function doesn't have any side effects, which is something I want to guarantee.

Comment: Then what comes into play here is thinking about writing 'pure' functions, that don't have side effects, which are easier test. Not always avoidable, however. Unit tests work best when they are designed around testing specific behavior of a function, given certain input. So in this case, writing a unit test to just make sure that if not `'new'` is passed in, then return `undefined`. Just something to keep in mind.